# How can I recover an unsaved Word 2016 document that wasn't found on a search of the computer?

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, microsoft-word-2016, file-recovery

I am on a Windows 10 laptop working in a local version of Word 2016 that's part of Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.  I had created a document on November 9 that I didn't save, although autosave is activated.  A Windows restart occurred due the installation of updates, and when the system came back up, the document was autorecovered.  On November 10, I didn't work on the document, and it remained open and unsaved, but Windows installed more updates and restarted again on the morning of November 11.  Yet, when the system came back up this time, the document wasn't autorecovered, although another document I'd been working that was saved did reopen.

I checked C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word and C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles, but the document wasn't there.  I performed a Windows search for all files w/ a .wbk, and it didn't come up.  I also went into Word and tried File > Info > Manage Document > Recover Unsaved Documents, and it didn't show there.  I finally checked the Recycle Bin, but

I'm at a loss of where to search next.  I know that I can try recovery software, but I thought that I would ask here first.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Install [voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and search for the file-name. Remember that the first character and maybe others might be replaced, so use some substrings. (I'm not asking why the document wasn't saved before or after the first Windows Update...)

Comment: "I know that I can try recovery software" - you should do that ASAP as IF the file i indeed deleted it can be overwritten any second.

Comment: Any methods to try in this link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/recover-lost-unsaved-corrupted-document

Answer (score 0):

You can look in c:\windows\temp and
%localappdata%\temp

It won't have the correct filename, you will kind of have to guess based on date, time, and size of the temporary file.  Also you may have to rename it with the correct extension.

Otherwise you will have to use data recovery software.